# Problem when upgrade package from python 2 to 3

Tags: python, arrays, python-2to3, ord

when running in python2, i get the result like this:

```
DEBUG:__main__:ASIC EEG Power: EEGPowerData(delta=7784, theta=7734, lowalpha=2035, highalpha=1979, lowbeta=2914, highbeta=3996, lowgamma=1944, midgamma=1847
```

when running in python3, the result is like this:

```
DEBUG:__main__:ASIC EEG Power: b'\x00\xa9\xf1\x00t%\x00\rK\x00\x18"\x00\x16%\x00\x1d6\x00OT\x00\x17\x84'
```

Anyone know how should i edit this line of code in order to make it work in python 3? Thank you

```
_decode = staticmethod(lambda v: EEGPowerData(*struct.unpack('>8L', ''.join( '\x00'+v[o:o+3] for o in range(0, 24, 3)))))
```

Comment: what's in the buffer and how do you fill that buffer? Any unicode char in a string would return itself as byte array instead of a string as in py2.

Comment: I think in that buffer is all byte code like "\xaa", the buffer is read from bluetooth. so how can I make it return a string in python 3? Thank you

Comment: Use something like `import six; data = six.ensure_text(mybytes) ##If you want to process as a string; ##Do further processing`

Comment: so does it mean I should change line 78 to buf = six.ensure_text(self.io.read(n))?

Comment: Yes try that out.

Comment: thanks. it report error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xaa in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: So in your ensure_text you can pass encoding as well like `ensure_text(mybytes, encoding='latin-1')`

Comment: I think it's still not decoding properly.

Comment: DEBUG:__main__:Unknown: code=80 extended_code_level=0 '\xff��'
DEBUG:__main__:Unknown: code=80 extended_code_level=0 '\x00\x08'
DEBUG:__main__:Unknown: code=80 extended_code_level=0 '\x00\x0b'
DEBUG:__main__:Unknown: code=80 extended_code_level=0 '\x00\x10'
DEBUG:__main__:Unknown: code=80 extended_code_level=0 '\x00\x0c'
DEBUG:__main__:Unknown: code=80 extended_code_level=0 '\x00\x15'

Comment: anyone could please help me with the problem? thank u!!!